# I can't configure my tablet's USB-to-ethernet IP setting manually

Tags: usb, internet, lenovo, ethernet

I have Lenovo A7-30 A3300 (A3300-GV) tablet on Android 4.4.2 which has USB ethernet support. My device is rooted but no application before root or after rooted work. I use a micro USB-to-ethernet adapter and it works fine with my router.

Where my internet is provided by local cable operator ISP Siti broadband or Alliance, IP address, subnet mask, default gateway, DNS must be set to PC ethernet IPv4 property or in a router. But when I directly connect it to my tab via USB ethernet, I can't configure it manually and the internet not working.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 0):

To display Ethernet settings in Android parameters you can edit `build.prop` file and search for "`ethernet`" word. On my Haier E701 Tablet, I've found the line:

```
ro.rk.ethernet_enable=false
```

I've replaced the "`false`" value by "`true`" and Ethernet settings are displayed.